# How to sort anchors within a table using JQuery sortable

Tags: jquery

I can't seem to sort my anchor tags within a table. I want to use the handle class in the anchor and be able to move/sort them where I want. What it's currently doing is moving the entire table instead.

Can someone show me where I'm going wrong?

```
<table id="test" border="1">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <a href="#" id="item_1" class="handle">item1</a>
      </td>
      <td>
        <a href="#" id="item_2" class="handle">item2</a>
      </td>
      <td">
        <a href="#" id="item_3" class="handle">item3</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
```

```
$("#test tbody a").sortable({
  handle : '.handle',
  update : function() {
    var order = $('#test tbody a').sortable('serialize');
    alert(order);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to understand what it is exactly you are trying to sort. Right now you have sortable() being called on your links ($("#test tbody a")), which is fine if you are trying to sort the links. However, it doesn't look like that's really the functionality you want. The reason that your links aren't sortable the way your code is set up now is because there is only one link in a cell -- so it can only be sorted with itself. If you call sortable() instead on the cell each link is in ($("#test td")), then you can sort the cells containing the links.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2E65V/)

PS: You also have an extra " character in one of your tds

```
  <td"> <!-- Here -->
    <a href="#" id="item_3" class="handle">item3</a>
  </td>
```

Comment: Ceili, Thanks for the explanation and the Fiddle. Very helpful.